# Vector::push_back() gives read access violation

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a problem with my class that only seems to come up when I try to add one of my objects to a vector.

Assignement works fine **unless it happens while trying to insert in a vector** (this results in the following error while deallocating memory: Exception thrown: read access violation `this->elements` was `0xCEDECEDF`).

Here is my assignement operator and my copy constructor. Note that `elements` is an `int**` pointer.

```
    Matrice& Matrice::operator=(const Matrice& other)
{
    if (elements)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < numberoflines; ++i)
            if (elements[i])
                delete[] elements[i];
        delete[] elements;
    }
    id = other.id;
    numberofcols= other.numberofcols;
    numberoflines= other.numberoflines;
    elements = new int*[numberoflines];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numberoflines; ++i)
        elements[i] = new int[numberofcols];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numberoflines; ++i)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < numberofcols; ++j)
            elements[i][j] = other.elements[i][j];
    return *this;
}
Matrice::Matrice(const Matrice& other) {
    *this = other;
}
```

Here is the header of `Matrice`(Matrix) class:

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
class Matrice {
public:
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Matrice&);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Matrice&);
    Matrice(const unsigned, const unsigned, const unsigned);
    Matrice();
    Matrice(const Matrice&);
    ~Matrice();
    Matrice& operator=(const Matrice&);
    int operator~()const;
    bool operator<(const Matrice&)const;
private:
    unsigned id;
    unsigned numberoflines;
    unsigned numberofcols;
    int** elements;
};
```

Here are the constructors and the destructor:

```
    Matrice::Matrice(unsigned id, unsigned numberoflines, unsigned numberofcols) {
    this->id = id;
    this->numberoflines = numberoflines;
    this->numberofcols = numberofcols;
    elements = new int*[numberoflines];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numberoflines; ++i)
        elements[i] = new int[numberofcols];
}
Matrice::Matrice() {
    numberofcols = 1;
    numberoflines = 1;
    elements = new int*[numberoflines];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numberoflines; ++i)
        elements[i] = new int[numberofcols];
}
Matrice::~Matrice() {
    if (elements) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < numberoflines; ++i)
            if (elements[i])
                delete[] elements[i];
        delete[] elements;
    }
}
```

And finally I just do this in **main**:

```
 std::vector<Matrice> vec;
    Matrice obj;
    vec.push_back(obj);
```

Comment: What `Matrice` class look like?

Comment: Do all your constructors initialize the `elements` member?  In modern C++ there is very rarely any good reason to ever use the `new` or `delete` keywords - just use a `vector` or smart pointer and avoid most of these problems.

Comment: I know this isn't the best approach but I had constraints from school to use `new` and `delete`

Comment: I presume you also implement the copy constructor and do so in terms of the copy assignment operator?

Comment: Sample code is not correct. You have `numberofcols` in one place, `nrcol` in another (presumably).

Comment: Yes, the copy constructor just simply calls the copy assignment operator.

Comment: What does your destructor look like?

Comment: OK, I might know the problem, but to be sure, show the copy constructor.

Comment: What happens if you set `elements=nullptr;` in your copy constructor *before* calling the assignment constructor? (this works for me)

Comment: (sorry -- it doesn't work perfectly. still working out other things)

Comment: It does work for me also. Thank you so much. I was the bottleneck in the project and I hated it. But do you have a reason for why this fixes the problem?

Comment: Yes; see the forthcoming answer.

Comment: I didn't see any errors while compiling your code in my IDE. Also see a live action here: https://www.ideone.com/ubzVEC

Comment: @JeJo I needed `valgrind` to find it. Seeing the error in a particular example may be compiler dependent.

Comment: You may want to do `if (this == &other) return *this;` at the top of your assignment operator, to protect from self-assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your copy constructor calls the assignment operator. The assignment operator starts with this code:

```
if (elements)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numberoflines; ++i)
        if (elements[i])
            delete[] elements[i];
    delete[] elements;
}
```

This will cause trouble in the copy constructor because nothing in the copy constructor has initialized `elements`, so it will point to a random place in memory. In your case, that was `0xCEDECEDF`. Hence `elements` is nonzero, which always evaluates as `true` in C++, so the code I've quoted above will try to delete memory that isn't, in fact, allocated.

Once you add the line `elements = nullptr;` to your copy constructor, the value of `elements` is now interpreted as `false`, so the `if` block is skipped, and the deallocation code isn't invoked.

Another way to do this [**in C++11**](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#member-init), which IMHO is wiser, is to initialize `nullptr` in the class declaration itself:

```
    unsigned numberofcols;
    int** elements = nullptr; // CHANGE HERE
};
```

This way, the compiler will initialize `elements` every time a new object is created and you don't have to worry about forgetting to do it in one of your constructors.

Your copy constructor has an oversight, by the way; you should first make sure that `this` and `other` aren't the same object.